# Variable for list index

Tags: python, list, variables, indexing

I am a beginner in python and I could really use some help.
I'm trying to create a variable to a index for my list.
The problem is that the variable becomes the current value in the list not an index.
Is there any way I could fix this (without creating a function)?

I would like that the variable 'one' should print '$'

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

one = my_list[0]

print(one)# 1

my_list[0] = '$'

print(one)# it still prints 1

print(type(one)) # <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, if you want the variable to be the index 0, you could set the variable to 0

`one = 0`

then access that element at index 0 using that variable

```
print(my_list[one])
>>>1
```

which will print the first element in my_list.

However I think what your asking is about why the variable one is not affected when you change the element in *my_list*

So the problem here is that when you create your variable called *one* you create a new variable which is a copy of *my_list[0]*.

this means that now you have two separate objects:

1. `one = 1`
2. `my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

this means that when you go to change the first element in my_list to '$' it will only affect *my_list* and the variable *one* will not be changed, so after doing

`my_list[0] = '$'`

you will have

1. one = 1
2. my_list = ['$',2,3,4,5,6]

so printing the variable *one* will still print 1.

Since your a beginner I don't think its too important to know exactly why it is like this, but if your interested you can look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/),
which talks about how variables are created and referenced in python.

Comment: thank you for you're time and answer, but what you're explaining is exactly my question, I would like a variable that acts like the index.

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
one=my_list[0]
print(one)
```

#here one is the old variable. after updating the 0 index, you were still using the old variable.

```
my_list[0]='$'
print(my_list[0])
output:
$
```